# Slow connection from PHP PDO app engine to Cloud SQL

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to deploy a PHP55 application to GAE (standard instances) with cloud SQL connection.

I'm using unix_socket DSN connection as shown in documentation, but the connection time to cloud sql instance is very very slow (it can take up to 200ms sometimes), and have a serious impact in application response time (it should answer in 50ms, but actually have an 150ms average response time) :

```
"timer (seconds)": {
            "begin": 0,
            "app": 0.043889999389648,
            "pdoinit": 0.000070095062255859,
            "pdook": 0.20270991325378,
            "pdoutf8": 0.037790060043335,
            "controller": 0.062999963760376,
            "preparequery": 0.015130043029785,
            "executequery": 0.0024099349975586,
            "return": 0.0051000118255615,
            "returnok": 0.00011014938354492
        }
```

Here is the same performance check from f1-micro compute engine instance :

```
"timer (seconds)": {
            "begin": 0,
            "app": 0.0002980232238769531,
            "pdoinit": 0.000014066696166992188,
            "pdook": 0.0019490718841552734,
            "pdoutf8": 0.0009219646453857422,
            "controller": 0.0030989646911621094,
            "preparequery": 0.005979061126708984,
            "executequery": 0.0009448528289794922,
            "return": 0.0031609535217285156,
            "returnok": 0.000025033950805664062
        },
```

My application and Cloud SQL instance are on the same location id. So no problem here.

Got another app accessing cloud SQL from compute engine in the same region, without any problem.

Maybe there is another connection method I did not see in the documentation ? I saw lot of people having problems like this, without solution. Maybe app engine is not the right solution ?

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The official CloudSQL documentation basically states that there are no alternative ways to connect to CloudSQL from AppEngine standard than the ways mentioned in the AppEngine documentation (i.e. sockets):

> **General information for connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine**
>
> When connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine standard or flex environment, you can connect only by using the instructions linked below. You cannot use IP addresses (public or private) to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine applications. Connections from App Engine applications to Cloud SQL are secure and encrypted; you do not need to configure TLS/SSL.

[SOURCE](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#general-info)

If it's an option for your application, you might try compute Engine vm's or kubernetes Engine, to be able to use regular tcp connections. Possibly even with private ip's, to increase the network performance.